# how to use klog level verbosity in golang?

Tags: go, logging

```
klog.V(1).Info("succesfully created deployment clientset in detailed")
```

is not priniting anything in command line though i imported

```
"github.com/kubernetes/klog"
```

.how to use debug level klogs using verbosity levels

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: I have the same issue. I grabbed code that uses klog from here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.16/test/images/agnhost/webhook. I tied also to add klog.SetOutput(os.Stdout) within the init method but I do not see any expted log entries in the stdout. I assume the klog.V(N)... match the -v N flag whe you use kubectll logs. Using "go.uber.org/zap" I see logs in stdout as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass "-v=1" to print it.

"-v=n" will print log entries with verbosity <= n.

Besides, if you write the program, you should also parse klog args before they take effect, put the code below in the begining of your main function:

```golang
klog.InitFlags(nil) // initializing the flags
defer klog.Flush()  // flushes all pending log I/O

flag.Parse() // parses the command-line flags

klog.Info("now you can see me")
```

Answer (score -3):

It will show output only if verbosity is enabled

Comment: Could you please show me how and where enable it? Thanks

Comment: enabling in the sense, if you are debugging ur code it will be enabled automatically .if u are running normally without debug it will be off

Comment: That's what I did it to enable the desired verbosity via flag ():
func main() {
 loggingFlags := flag.NewFlagSet("webhook", flag.ExitOnError)
 loggingFlags.StringVar(....).
 klog.InitFlags(loggingFlags)
 loggingFlags.Parse(os.Args[1:])
....